# NSManagedObject auto saving some properties?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` which I use to populate a `UITableView` with some saved `NSManagedObjects` (each of which has an `NSMutableAttributedString` property). After the user selects a cell, I retrieve the corresponding `NSManagedObject`, pass it to the next view controller, and set the `NSFetchedResultsController` to nil. On the next view controller, I edit the `NSManagedObject`'s `NSMutableAttributedString` and DON'T save it. Here is my problem, if I now go back to the previous view controller, and reselect the same `NSManagedObject` from the same cell, the `NSMutableString` still has the same edits that I made previously. Does anyone know why this is and how I can prevent it? Some code snippets:

In my app delegate:

```
- (NSString *) saveContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSError *error;

    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        return [error localizedDescription];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

The view controller which has the `UITableView` and `fetechedResultsController`:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSError *error;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
}


    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }

    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
        if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        {
            return _fetchedResultsController;
        }

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ComicInfo" inManagedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastSaved" ascending:NO];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:9];

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                       cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        return _fetchedResultsController;

    }
```

Comment: If the original NSManagedObjectContext is re-associated with the nil'd NSFetchedResultsController, the managed object will be returned. I'm guessing that's the answer, but would like to see some code before I submit it as such.

Comment: @JShapiro - I put up some code. Even so though, if I'm not saving the context, how is it still saving the NSMutableAttributedString? And the funny thing is it only selects that and neglects to save other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSFetchedResultsController doesn't really save anything. It's the NSManagedObjectContext that saves (or changes) things.  Even though you create a new NSFetchedResultsController, you keep re-associating it with the same NSManagedObjectContext:

```
...inManagedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext]]
```

So think of it this way: a managed object has all of its changes.. well.. managed, by the NSManagedObjectContext.  If you create a new NSFetchedResultsController with the **same** NSManagedObjectContext, any request for that managed object will be the same (regardless if it's been saved or not - unless you've killed the app).

In other words, while the app is still running, the NSManagedObjectContext will return the same managed object it has in memory when asked... even if it's associated with a new NSFetchedResultsController.  Saving is a whole different activity.  Saving an object means it'll be alive even after its environment has been shut down.  But in this case, you're not shutting down the environment (NSManagedObjectContext).  As a test you could try this:  have the 2nd VC make the change to the managed object, but kill the application (not just suspend) before you return to the first VC.  Then re-start the app, I bet you won't see any of the changes made (since you didn't save it).

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. So I guess the solution would be to set the NSManagedObjectContext to nil first when I load that first view controller with the tableview?

Comment: If you don't want the second VC to change the original managed object, make a copy: [obj copy] and work with that.